# How do I extract data from 2 tables (in sql server) by using angular js

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, ajax

I need your help because I have no much experience. The fact is that I need to extract data from 2 tables stored in (the same database) SQL Server. I want to use the data from this two tables by inserting it in a table within an html document. So, I'm using a js script to get data but only from one table (Table1). Below there is a piece of code, where I use an 'url' and it belongs to my Table1 :

"ajax": {
            "url": "/Table/GetList/",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": { 'data': myJSONText },
        },

Thank you!

Yes, the two tables are related. The project it's been developed on ASP.NET Razor C#.

Comment: are the data between the 2 tables related ?

Comment: This is less a question of your client side scripts (angular), and more a question of your API.  What are you writing your REST API in?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this from you API you I guess you won't be able to do this from here unless you put two post request where as from you REST API OR Back-End you can put join between two tables and get whatever you want.